# Inheritance in Java (public or private for class fields?)

Tags: java

```
public class Square {
  public double height;
  public double width;
  public double surfaceArea;

  Square(double height, double width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  public double getHeight() {
    return this.height;
  }

  public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public double getWidth() {
    return this.width;
  }

  public double computeSurfaceArea() {
    this.surfaceArea = this.height * this.width;
    return this.surfaceArea;
  }

  public double getSurfaceArea() {
    return this.surfaceArea;
  }
}

public class Cube extends Square {
  private int depth = 6;

  Cube(double height, double width) {
    super(height, width);
  }

  public double computeSurfaceArea() {
    super.surfaceArea = (super.height * super.width) * depth;
    return super.surfaceArea;
  }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoSquare {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Square square;
    Cube cube;

    double doubleValue1, doubleValue2;

    System.out.print("Enter value for height: \n>> ");
    doubleValue1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter value for width: \n>> ");
    doubleValue2 = input.nextDouble();

    square = new Square(doubleValue1, doubleValue2);
    cube = new Cube(doubleValue1, doubleValue2);

    System.out.println("\n<Results>\n");
    System.out.println("Surface area of <Square Class>: " + square.computeSurfaceArea());
    System.out.println("Surface area of <Cube Class>: " + cube.computeSurfaceArea());
  }
}
```

Is it okay if I make my class fields(Parent class) to public rather than private? It's because im using the concept of inheritance right here. Or should I use the getters/setters method in the parent class.

Comment: "Is it okay if I do X" is not really a technical question. It's same as "will my friends still like me if I do X".

Comment: *"Is it okay if I make my class fields(Parent class) to public rather than private?"* ... if your goal is to try and adhere as best you can to the tenets of object-oriented programming (i.e. encapsulation and data hiding), then one can say that this is never a good idea.

Comment: I'm disappointed that nobody yet has pointed out the modelling error: a `Cube` isn't a `Square` - they're simply different beasties, and so shouldn't be related types. Additionally, the calculation of the surface area of a `Cube` is wrong - you're calculating the volume, not the surface area.

Comment: I suggest you learn about `protected` access.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use protected  instead of public. It will also serve ur purpose of inheritance and other class needs to use setter methods to modify fields.

Comment: *"You should use protected instead of public."* ... the use of the protected modifier should be pretty rare and should extend only to those things that really, really must be shared with subclasses.  Going from package-private to protected is a huge increase in visibility.  It is the difference between a field being an implementation detail that is decoupled from clients ... to a fully supported member of the class's exported API.

Comment: @scottb agreed..

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good practice to use getters and setters to access fields of the class even though public modifiers are allowed

Comment: what's better for parent class fields? public or private?

Answer (score 0):

You should use, most of the time, the private modifier for class fields, but in case of inheritance, you should mark protected only the fields you think the subclass needs to have access to.

In addition to that, you should use getters/setters most of the time. Using public may cause inappropriate use of the class, like using not the way you wanted, cause you can't control the given values (In this example, negative width).

You should read about the key concepts of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

The most important feature of OOP is *information hiding* That means that other classes have **no knowledge at all** about the internal structure of a class.

However, *getter* and *setter* **expose** this internal structure as well as *non private* member variable do.

There is a kind of Objects we use as dump data store for which we want to expose the internal structure. These are *Value Objects* or *Data Transfer Objects* which have no logic of their own (except very basic validations).

Your classes contain business logic. This mean they are not VOs/DTOs and therefore they should not have *getter* or *setter*.

Also your code uses *inheritance* in a wrong way.

When we have a class `B` extending a class `A` then we establish an **is a** relationship. In real life: would you say "A cube **is a** square"? Hopefully you would rather say: "A cube **consists** of 6 squares". And that's how I would implement it:

```
class Square{
  // edges of a suare have all same length
  private final double edgeLengthInMeter;
  public Square(double edgeLengthInMeter){
    this.edgeLengthInMeter = edgeLengthInMeter; 
  }
  public double calculateArea(){
    return edgeLengthInMeter*edgeLengthInMeter;
  }
}

class Cube {
  // cubes have 6 equal squares as surface
  private final Square surfaces;
  public Cube(Square surfaces){
    this.surfaces = surfaces;
  }    
  public double calculateArea(){
    return 6*surfaces.calculateArea();
  }
}
```

Looking at the classes we see that they have a common method `calculateArea()`.
Here is where we introduce inheritance: we extract a common *interface*:

```
interface Surface {
 double calculateArea();
}
```

and we let your classes implement that interface:

```
class Square implements Surface{
  // edges of a suare have all same length
  private final double edgeLengthInMeter;
  public Square(double edgeLengthInMeter){
    this.edgeLengthInMeter = edgeLengthInMeter; 
  }
  @Override
  public double calculateArea(){
    return edgeLengthInMeter*edgeLengthInMeter;
  }
}

class Cube  implements Surface{
  // cubes have 6 equal squares as surface
  private final Square surfaces;
  public Cube(Square surfaces){
    this.surfaces = surfaces;
  }
  @Override
  public double calculateArea(){
    return 6*surfaces.calculateArea();
  }
}
```

Now we can hold `Square`s and `Cube`s in the same list:

```
 List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
 surfaces.add(new Square(2.5));
 surfaces.add(new Cube(new Square(7.042)));

 for(Surface surface : surfaces)
   System.out.println(surface.calculateArea());
```

Answer (score 0):

This falls in to the concept of encapsulation, In object oriented programming is a good practice to only allow the same class to make changes to its fields, this to provide means for securing the integrity of the values, You can provide methods within the class to validate new values before the class fields are changed. I you want other classes to have access to this fields is when the getters and setters come in to place giving a more structured way to work with instances of the class. Now in your example if you want to make those fields accesible from the child class YES they can be public or better as some one blow mentioned make them "protected" in order for the child class to be able to use them directly or you can do:

`super.surfaceArea = (super.getheight() * super.getwidth()) * depth;`

And now you can make height and width private fields.

now it would be better to have a method to calculate surface area from within the super class.

```
public void setsurfacearea()
{
this.surfacearea = this.width*this.height;
}
```

setsurfacearea() can be called every time after you change width or height to update the surface area.